# Playframework Scala play-slick3-example project: JdbcSQLException: Column "TEST" not found

Tags: scala, jdbc, playframework, h2, slick

I downloaded a starter application with Play Framework 2.5 and Slick 3.1, [git here](https://github.com/nemoo/play-slick3-example#master).

When I add a simple to column named "test" to [Project.scala](https://github.com/nemoo/play-slick3-example/blob/master/app/models/Project.scala). I get this error:

```
[JdbcSQLException: Column "TEST" not found; SQL statement:
select "ID", "NAME", "TEST" from "PROJECT" [42122-187]]
```

I just change the **Project** case class by adding the argument test and **ProjectsTable** class with functions test, * and ?:

```
case class Project(id: Long, name: String, test: String)


private class ProjectsTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Project](tag, "PROJECT") {

  def id = column[Long]("ID", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("NAME")
  def test = column[String]("TEST")

  def * = (id, name, test) <> (Project.tupled, Project.unapply)
  def ? = (id.?, name.?, test.?).shaped.<>({ r => import r._; _1.map(_ => Project.tupled((_1.get, _2.get, _3.get))) }, (_: Any) => throw new Exception("Inserting into ? projection not supported."))

}
```

And the function: create

```
def create(name: String): Future[Long] = {
  val project = Project(0, name, "d")
  db.run(Projects returning Projects.map(_.id) += project)
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the field `test` to the `ProjectsTable` model you are telling Slick that the database table `PROJECT` has a column named `test` - but the table `PROJECT` does not have a column named `test`.

You can see the SQL schema here: https://github.com/nemoo/play-slick3-example/blob/6c122970d7506bedb9230e3a31c30a5c7e27e93b/conf/evolutions/default/1.sql